# Vim Search/Replace, meaning of %s

Tags: vim, replace

In Vim you can search/replace text in the following way.

```
:%s/old/new
```

What does the %s mean?

Comment: in vim type `:h range` you will see details. I bet it would be very helpful for your daily editing, if you use vim. :)

Comment: That's a very basic Vi(m) question; looks like you're a beginner. Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: I am vim beginner.  I see its potential to be much faster than most IDE's once these commands are learned but for me its much easier to remember when I have a solid understanding of what everything stands for!  Thanks all!

Comment: `E149: Sorry, no help for %s` so you have to already know the answer to know to get the help for `range` instead. So it's a perfectly good beginner question.

Comment: @IngoKarkat Hot take: SO should not have a barrier for entry where all questions have to be beyond beginner level. So long as the question isn't solved by an exact duplicate, we should welcome users of all abilities to ask questions and solve problems here. What's intuitive and obvious to one is not to another.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`%` is the range over which the `:s` command (short for `:substitute`) will be run.  `%` itself is short for the range `:1,$`, which means `Line 1 to the last line in the buffer`.

The Vim help has a couple topics (user manual - [:help 10.3](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_10.txt.html#10.3), reference manual - [:help cmdline-ranges](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-ranges)) describing the forms that ranges can take.

Answer (score 18):

The syntax for `:s` (which is short for `:substitute`) is:

```
:[range]s[ubstitute]/{pattern}/{string}/[flags] [count]
```

The `%` range means "the whole file".

This is very powerful; if you would want to do substitutions on just line 1, you would use:

```
:1s/a/b/
```

Or, for just lines 1 to 3:

```
:1,3s/a/b/
```

A very useful (related) trick, is to highlight lines with visual mode (`V`), and then use `:s` to substitute just on the lines you highlighted.

See: [`:help [range]`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%5brange%5d)

Answer (score 2):

```
:%s/old/new/
```

This will search the entire document for "old" and replace the first instance on each line with "new".  You can use `:%s/old/new/g` to replace all instances of "old" with "new".

(Updated based answer on jamessan's comment).

Comment: Not quite.  It will replace the first instance of `old` on each line with `new`.  You need the g flag to `:s` if you want to replace all instances.

Comment: Good point, I'm so use to adding the 'g' option that I assume it's there.

Answer (score 1):

**%s** stands for the whole document. See here:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges

Comment: typo, `%` is range of whole buffer, but `%s` isn't. :D